# Layered navigation product count issue after elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, elasticsearch

We are facing issue in layered navigation product count after enabling elastic search in Magento 2.3.1

[Link which was working earlier before enabling elastic search](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Incorrect-product-count-in-layered-navigation-after-overriding/m-p/104534#M5628)

Now, this file is not called.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You got any solution? for me also same issue